# Issue with setting ADMIN password on Windows CE

Tags: authentication, passwords, windows-ce, platform-builder

I have wrote a user manager script the uses [`NTLMSetUserInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms926215.aspx) to set passwords of some users, including `ADMIN`... What I have noticed though is that if I do this the username / password combination works perfectly for all scenarios such as Telnet, HTTP Auth etc but NOT file browsing.

Upon further inspection I noticed that when setting the Admin password through the built in CE configuration web pages it works.

The registry for Admin looks like so when I use `NTLMSetUserInfo`

```
NT = [hex value]
```

The registry for Admin contains an extra field, `Password` when I set the admin password via the CE web pages.

```
NT = [hex value]
Password = [hex value]
```

I figure `NTLMSetUserInfo` doesn't set the global CE password for Admin properly, hence not being able to file browse onto the box.

I found the following function in the CE web code parsing DLL that does the job called [`SetPassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915490.aspx).  I wrote a separate function to deal with Admin cases but I cannot get it to compile.  Here is a snippet of it

```
#include <windbase.h>

bool UserAccounts::SetAdminPassword(const std::string &passwordOld, const std::string &password)
{
    wchar_t wpass[512];
    wchar_t wpassold[512];

    mbstowcs(wpass, password.c_str(), 512);
    mbstowcs(wpassold, passwordOld.c_str(), 512);

    return SetPassword(wpassold, wpass) == TRUE;
}
```

This will not compile stating that `'SetPassword': identifier not found`.  I notice in the [CE documentation for `SetPassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915490.aspx) it has the following line

> To use this function, you must include
>   the password component, Fspass, in
>   your Cesysgen.bat file.

I'm not sure what this means as I am pretty new to PlatformBuilder etc...

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your code file:

```
extern "C" BOOL SetPassword(LPWSTR lpszOldPassword, LPWSTR lpszNewPassword);
```

The linker will do the rest.

Comment: Yeah, it's the shortcut when you can't find the header.  I tend to do this a lot for functions I know are there, but I can't find the declaration (TouchCalibrate, SetPassword, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I can't give an exact answer right now (never used this authentication). But, I just tried to use (actually compile) `SetPassword` in a cloned version of the bluetooth AudioGateway driver I have and it compiles without problems.

When I tried to use it in a subproject or a regular independent project I had the same error that you got. So a quick solution might be to do this in a driver and see if it works.

Regarding the comment in the docs I assume they it goes down to having the `SYSGEN_FSPASSWORD` selected in the catalog though I did not trace this yet. I guess you have this selected if you can set passwords and such.

Comment: @Shaihi.  Thanks for the response.  Our SDK has SYSGEN_FSPASSWORD compiled in so can't imagine that component isn't part of the SDK.  Do you know what LIB it is part of so I can link to it?

Comment: I just added it to a regular driver and it compiled as well. I guess it resides in `coredll`. I searched for the function name in the `coredll.dll` in the release directory and it shows there. Did you try to add the call to a driver?